# Spring ORM support for JDBC?

Tags: spring

as it is stated at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/orm.html

The Spring Framework provides integration with Hibernate, JDO, Oracle TopLink, iBATIS SQL Maps and JPA:

My question here is does not spring provide ORM support for JDBC?

Comment: that's an ancient link for an ancient version. This is the current version: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spring supports JDBC, and includes helper objects to map resultsets to objects, if that's what you mean.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html) It's not listed on the page you link to because it's not considered to be an ORM. (Actually Ibatis isn't considered to be an ORM either, it's a "data mapper".)

Comment: As you said it's not considered to be an ORM . Is it bacause of the reason In JDBC that we are extracting the values manually and putting it in java data objects but in case of other frameworks like hibernate we directly get the java objects?

Comment: @Mohit: ORMs try harder to abstract away the database more or less completely. Hibernate controls object identity with its 1st level cache, reorders queries, and allows apps to be portable across RDBMS vendors.